# Questions regarding rules of chanting Vedas

Tags: scripture, vedas, practice

- Can  I learn Vedas through MP3 and Cassette?
- Can I chant Vedas even if I don't understand the meaning?

Comment: for chanting you need it to learn it from a veda pathi. there are many rules of pronunciation and chanting.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi I am just asking whether it is allowed to chant Vedas even if we don't understand the meaning

Comment: if you have learned from guru or pathshala then u can chant without understanding also not a problem.

Comment: in addition, you must also be a dvija to learn Vedas i.e. you must have had upanayana done, do sandhya-vandana, and follow other shastras. (I already know other people on this site won't accept this fact, but their arguments hold no water)

Comment: @ram I accepted already the fact. I am only asking this for Dvijas

Comment: initially you need to learn from guru, by repeating each verse twice. after a few sessions, once you have learnt pronunciation and can read the verses from book, then you can use audio to supplement your memory and correct errors. we should not learn directly from cassette, because we don't know who the original chanter is, and we did not give them dakshina (see ekalavya story)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A partial answer.

> Can I chant Vedas even if I don't understand the meaning?

Chanting after understanding the meanings is what is recommended.

> Knowing the metre and the Rishi (saintly author), one should zealously
>   recite the Mantrams. And **knowing their meaning**, a twice-born one
>   should mentally recite the Gayatri, day and night
>
> **Harita Smriti, Chapter 1.**

................

> The Brahmacharin, who, **understanding its meaning** daily reads the
>   Gayatri, the mother of the Vedas, comes by the most excellent
>   condition. (53)
>
> O ye twice-born ones, having studied [either] one, or two, or three,
>   of the Vedas, or the [entire] four Vedas
>   **and understood their meaning properly,** the foremost of the twice-born should [celebrate the occasion with the terminating] bath.
>   (86) )
>
> **Usana Smriti, Chapter 3.**

NOTE: When i find an explicit reference which says reciting Vedas is futile unless the meaning  too is understood, i will add it.